# Programming a UART directly in assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, uart

I'm attempting to write a assembler function to read and echo characters for the following C callable function

```
void echo(int comport, unsigned char esc_char)
```

Basically it prompts you for an ESC character then after the user types one it allows you to keep typing and terminates the program if that character is typed. My implementation allows the user to assign the ESC character but stops after typing the first letter for anything after that, which I believe may be some sort of infinite loop. How do I go about resolving this?

Ideally the program would run like this

> ```
> Type escape character and enter
> d
> abc(d)
> Escape character typed - exiting.
> ```

But what's happening so far is

> ```
> Type escape character and enter
> p
> a
> (Program Freezes)
> ```

```
.text
.globl _echo
_echo:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $8, %esp
    movb 12(%ebp), %bl  
    movl 8(%ebp), %edx  

    xorl %ecx, %ecx
    movb $0xfc, %dl
    inb (%dx), %al
    orb $0x03, %al
    outb %al, (%dx)
    movb $0xfe, %dl  
loop1:
    inb (%dx), %al  
    andb $0xb0, %al  
    xorb $0xb0, %al  
    jnz loop1
loop2:
    movl $0xfd, %dl 
    inb (%dx), %al  
    andb $0x01, %al 
    jz loop2        
    movl $0xf8, %dl 
    inb (%dx), %al  
    movb %al, %al   
    cmpb %cl, %bl
    je return
    movb $0xfd, %dl 
type:
    inb (%dx), %al  
    andb $0x20, %al
    jz loop2        
    movzbl %dl, %eax    
    movl $0xf8, %edx    
    outb %al, (%dx) 
    jmp loop2
return:
    mov %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
    .end
```

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, use a debugger to single step the program and see where it goes wrong yourself. Finally, consider if you even need assembly for this. Normally you only have the `in`/`out` as assembly the rest is C. PS: as per the usual calling convention `ebx` is a callee-saved register.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure this is it

Comment: that first `movb $0xfc, %dl` should target `al`? The `dx` is already loaded by `movl 8(%ebp), %edx` from argument... did you at least some basic debugging to remove obvious problems? Then you should comment the code to make clear the double-loading `edx` is not a mistake, but intent. (I didn't read the code further, as the `ebx` + weirdness of code is enough for a start). Feels like freshly written code without any debugging effort at all, that's not worth commenting, as there will be probably several bugs on every other line.

Comment: @Ped7g, this function is intended to be called with the first parameter equal to 0x3f8 or 0x2f8. Each com port consists of 8 consecutive I/O ports. dl is loaded before each port access to specify which of the 8 ports is being accessed. It would be better to do `mov 8(%ebp), %edi` and then `lea xx(%edi), %edx` to set up dx for each port. With that change, this code would work with any com port address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the character from the port, you have

```
    movb %al, %al
```

It should be

```
    movb %al, %cl
```

Then, after checking THR_EMPTY, you have

```
    movzbl %dl, %eax
```

It should be

```
    movb %cl, %al
```